# Using sed with e substitution option: s///e

Tags: sed

I'm having a problem using the sed substitution option that executes a command in the replacement pattern. I believe the option is an extensions to [GNU sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.txt) but I haven't been able to find any documentation on it. Anyone know of any?

My problem is that I can't extract the matching text properly when using the execute replacement option. I'm using GNU sed 4.2 on Mac OSX 10.7.4

```
echo "12345678\r" | sed 's/.*/echo "&);"/e'

Result: );345678
Desired Result: 12345678);
```

I've tried using different regex matches, such as \d+, but that just seems to break the ability to use the /e substitution option. And I've tried using an explicit capture group such as \1 instead of & but that also seems to break the /e option.

**Update:**

My example was perhaps oversimplified what I'm ultimately trying to do is take a text file with each line holding a unique value and pass that to sed and use the uuidgen command (in the same manner as a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167500/add-new-uuid-to-each-line-of-a-file-using-sed-or-equivalent-command) I posted). The new problem I've got is because I'm now running the command on a Mac the \r is not being stripped from the matched string.

The full command I want to execute is:

```
sed 's/.*/echo "blah blah `uuidgen`,&):"/e' file.txt
```

**Update 2:**

In my Mac terminal I don't need to use echo -e to get \r interpreted as a line feed and in fact according to "man echo" there is no -e option. It does make life difficult moving between all the terminal environments :(.

Thanks to kev I was able to come up with a solution that worked on Mac.

```
sed 's/\r//; s/.*/ echo "blah blah (`uuidgen`,&);"/e' file.txt
```

Comment: GNU sed 4.2 on Mac OSX 10.7.4

Comment: The `e` option is documented in the [GNU `sed` manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `e` flag:

```
$ echo "12345678\r" | sed 's/.*/echo "&);"/'
echo "12345678\r);"
```

Add `e` flag is the same as:

```
$ echo -e "12345678\r);"
);345678
```

---

You can remove the `\r`:

```
$ echo "12345678\r" | sed -e 's/\\r//' -e 's/.*/echo "&);"/'
12345678);
```

Comment: The \r is what I'm trying to cope with in the real input to the sed command.

Comment: The two stage sed command sorted it for me, I should have thought of that.

Comment: Why is the `\r` present at all?  Data from Windows?  Convert to Unix before processing.  Consider using the `tr` command to remove the `\r`.

Comment: Yes the file is from Windows. How do you apply tr to a stream? The sed approach of s/\r// was perfect.

Answer (score 2):

> );345678

What `echo` outputs is `12345678` followed by `\r` which takes the cursor back to beginning of line and the `);` resulting in the string you see in the window. Put a `|od -cx` at the end of command to see.

On my `cygwin` install I need `echo -e` to get the similar behavior. I am not able to remove `\r` in `sed` but I am able to do by adding `tr`:

```
$ echo "12345678\r" | sed 's/.*/echo -e "&);"/e'| tr -d "\r"
12345678);
```