# Replace each matched string value with unique uuid on Linux and OSX

Tags: linux, bash, macos, sed

I have a folder with a bunch of files. In some of those files there is a line like this

```
id = "8c09e1ce-56b6-4aa5-8307-8998f507b594"
```

All those `id`s are unique.

I want to write a command that will generate new unique values for all those `id`s

I have a `sed` command that will match the original line `'s/id = \"[a-zA-Z0-9-]\{36\}\"//g'` but I don't know how I can dynamically get the substitution working.

There are a few StackOverflow questions that are similar ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167500/add-new-uuid-to-each-line-of-a-file-using-sed-or-equivalent-command)) but I couldn't get the solution to work reliably across OSX and Linux which is one of my requirements. They all have `uuidgen` installed though.

Something concise and readable would obviously be preferred.

Comment: What is the expected output for the ID string you have mentioned.

Comment: hey @Inian I want to replace the guid value with a new guid in all those files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For in-placing editing with `sed`'s `-i` option, there is no cross-platform syntax that works *without* creating a backup file, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40777793/45375) of mine (you must use *either* `-i ''` (BSD/macOS) *or* just `-i` (GNU), but *with* creation of a backup file something like `-i.bak` does work with both implementations).

That said, `awk` is the better tool for this task anyway, because Awk scripts allow invoking shell commands and external utilities on demand:

```
find . -type f -name '*.extension' | while IFS= read -r fpath; do
  awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS=" = " } 
    $2 ~ /^\"[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\"$/ { "uuidgen" | getline uuid; $2 = "\"" uuid "\"" }
    1
  ' "$fpath" > "$fpath.tmp" && mv "$fpath.tmp" "$fpath"
done
```

<sup>This assumes that filenames have no embedded newlines, which is rarely a real-world concern.</sup>

- The command uses only POSIX-compliant shell features, utilities and options, with the exception of:

  - the `uuidgen` utility, which, however, is available on both Linux and macOS, as well as FreeBSD and its variants.
- Sadly, Mawk (which is Ubuntu's default Awk) doesn't support duplication expressions such as `{36}`, which is why the less specific `+` is used above; if you know that you'll be using only either BSD or GNU Awk, however, you can still use `{36}`.
- The command supports replacing *multiple* UUIDs in each input file.

On a side note: *GNU* Awk v4.1+ allows in-place updating with `-i inplace`, similar to Sed's `-i` option, which would allow for a single-command `find` solution with `-exec`, but neither BSD Awk nor Mawk support it.

Answer (score -2):

So I figured it out (by cheating).

There's only one `id` per file so I decided to iterate over the files and run `sed` for each file separately, like this:

```
for i in `find . -name "*.extension" -type f`; do
    uuid=$(uuidgen)
    sed -i '' -e "s/id = \"[a-zA-Z0-9-]\{36\}\"/id = \"${uuid}\"/g" $i
done
```

The question still stands though for a general case, if that can be done in one go.

Comment: Please [do not use `for` to parse command output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). Also, your `sed -i ''` only works with _BSD_ Sed, not with _GNU_ Sed. Please double-quote `$i` to ensure that its value is used as-is. The `g` option in the Sed script's `s` function call is not needed, because there's at most 1 UUID per input line.